# How to prevent Chome and Edge from showing saved payment methods drop down for an input that is NOT payment related

Tags: forms, google-chrome, razor, autocomplete, payment-method

We have a field on a form that is used for numeric data that is part of a date.  In both edge and Chrome, the saved payment methods show up as suggestions under this field.  We already have autocomplete="off" set on the field.  It's a bit different than the normal saved fields auto complete though, since it's specifically prompting them to pick a saved payment method    It would be okay if it showed the previous data that's valid for that field, or didn't try to make suggestions at all.  As it is it's causing frustration for the users who are putting a credit card number in an inappropriate field.  Our system does not do anything with credit card numbers either.

What about a field makes Chrome or Edge think it's a payment /credit card number field?  How can we prevent this?   Already tried autocomplete="nope" as has been suggested elsewhere with no luck. These are .net razor pages if it makes a difference.  I could add something in jquery or change the name or well anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

Martian,  In addition to the things you set on the fields themselves the actual name of the field may be triggering this behavior. If for example you have a field name cardnumber, or card, then this may cause the autofill to identify the field as such and provide the suggestions. Try renaming your field to something that is unrelated and it should stop prompting you.